# How to get line number(s) in the StackTrace of an exception thrown in .NET 6 on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, exception, stack-trace

I am compiling under .NET 6 Framework (I also tried .NET Core 3.1) C# code in Visual Studio

Though it works perfectly well under Windows, with the same options, I cannot get the line number(s) in the StackTrace of an exception under Linux (Ubuntu 18.04).

- pdb files are present
- installed .NET 6 on the Linux machine
- Deployment mode : self-contained

Comment: Did you compile with Debug or Release configuration?

Comment: Release, but I tried debug as well for testing and it did not help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this method. I wrote it when I needed the line number from which error occurs.

```
''' <summary>
''' 
''' </summary>
''' <param name="ex"></param>
Public Sub ErrorShow(ByVal ex As Exception)
    Dim Result As String
    Dim hr As Integer = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHRForException(ex)
    Result = ex.GetType.ToString & "(0x" & hr.ToString("X8") & "): " & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & ex.StackTrace & Environment.NewLine
    Dim st As StackTrace = New StackTrace(ex, True)
    For Each sf As StackFrame In st.GetFrames
        If sf.GetFileLineNumber() > 0 Then
            Result &= "Line:" & sf.GetFileLineNumber() & " Filename: " & IO.Path.GetFileName(sf.GetFileName) & Environment.NewLine
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(Result)
End Sub
```